# CORS in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cors

I have created a basic web services in ASP.Net 3.5. Now when I try to access it from different domain it giving me error. I tried many thing to enable CORS but failed to do so. Please help me to sort this out.

**dealsfeed.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Man.Utility;
using Man.Helper;

using System.ServiceModel.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for dealsfeed
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class dealsfeed : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public dealsfeed () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        try
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            return "Processor Usage" + ex.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>

    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>  
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
          The <authentication> section enables configuration 
          of the security authentication mode used by 
          ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <!--
           The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
           of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
           during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
           it enables developers to configure html error pages 
           to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
        -->
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
          <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Script**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://deals.giftyourfeelings.co.in/services/dealsfeed.asmx/HelloWorld",
  method: "GET",
  dataTypa:"jsonp",
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly go through the article for [Enabling CORS in ASP.NET Server](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html). You need to configure IIS to enable it. If not, you can enable by using the following code:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Add this code to your configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

To enable cross-origin requests, add the [EnableCors] attribute to your Web API controller or controller method:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

The method described above can also be used to enable CORS across the API without annotating each controller:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```